# Debug extension in Magento admin panel

Tags: php, magento

Is there any way, I can debug and find out why the extension link in not appearing under `Configuration` in the left sidebar.

I have tried enabling debugging by placing following code in `.htaccess` file in the root folder of Magento with no luck:

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE true

php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/path/public_html/var/log/system.log
```

Comment: Check your modules system.xml and also enable logs and check system log

Comment: can you post your syatem.xml?

Comment: This extension is working on one Magento installation but not on the another. So this doesn't seem issue with `system.xml`. Also, I have followed the cache cleaning, compilation enable/disable processs. Any thoughts?